# Why is the the default value of mboxDefault visibility: hidden? (Adobe Test&Target)

Tags: adobe

I'm trying to wrap a banner on a webpage with an mbox div but it disappears once I run it on my local host because the visibility is set to hidden. I know that I can force the visibility to visible by doing this:

```
<div class="mboxDefault" style="visibility: visible;"> 
content abc 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">mboxCreate('mboxabc');</script>
```

but is that the correct way to go about it? Do I really have to add styling to force it to show my default content? I thought mbox will only set my visibility to hidden when I chose to pull in snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target set the mbox divs to be non-visible (class mboxDefault) to avoid that the user sees default content for a brief time before target changes that with the appropriate offer.

When target script finishes loading it will show the content on the mbox div, either with the replaced content from an offer, or with the default content if the user got the default experience.